# first_value and last_value for each user id

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to get the first scheduled start time and last scheduled end time for each user in my scheduled_jobs table for a date.

I can get it to work for one user, but when trying for all users per day I can get the last time, but the cannot get the correct first time it is displaying the time for the first user_id for all user_id's.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (user_id)
    user_id, first_value(scheduled_jobs.at) over (order by user_id, scheduled_jobs.at ASC),
    last_value(scheduled_jobs.to) over (order by user_id, scheduled_jobs.at DESC)
FROM scheduled_jobs
WHERE scheduled_jobs.at between CURRENT_DATE+INTERVAL'3 day' and CURRENT_DATE +INTERVAL '4 day'
```

Example of current results:

```
user_id | first_value         | last_value
  19    | 2018-10-29 07:00:00 | 2018-10-29 17:00:00
  30    | 2018-10-29 07:00:00 | 2018-10-29 15:00:00
  37    | 2018-10-29 07:00:00 | 2018-10-29 16:30:00
```

Last_value is showing correctly for each user_id, however first_value is always showing the value for the first user_id for all.

I have tried spliting  them into different SELECT queries with a JOIN and a USING query but still getting incorrect results for the first_value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `PARTITION BY` clause, which generates the frame per `user_id`

```
SELECT DISTINCT on (user_id)
    user_id, 
    first_value(sj.at) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY sj.at ASC),
    last_value(sj.to) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY sj.at DESC)
FROM 
    scheduled_jobs sj
WHERE 
    sj.at BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE + 3 and CURRENT_DATE + 4
```

---

**Addionally**: Please be careful by using `last_value`. Sometimes it would not work as expected. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42299101/window-functions-last-valueorder-by-asc-same-as-last-valueorder-by-d)

You should use `first_value` with `DESC` ordering instead:

```
first_value(scheduled_jobs.at) over (partition by user_id order by scheduled_jobs.at DESC)
```

Comment: Yes this solved my problem by adding the partition in, as did the answer above

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `min()` and `max()`? As you don't select any additional columns, there is no need for `distinct on()` or window functions to begin with:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       min(scheduled_jobs.at),
       max(scheduled_jobs.at)
FROM scheduled_jobs
WHERE scheduled_jobs.at between CURRENT_DATE + 3 and CURRENT_DATE + 4
group by user_id;
```

When you want to add days to a `DATE` value, you don't need use an `interval`, you can just add an integer

Comment: Yes this solved my problem, maybe I was over complicating it. The answer below also worked. It only lets me mark one as an accepted answer though.