# Using postgres window functions with different order by clause

Tags: postgresql

I have an issue using multiple order by in postgres window functions. Here is short example. Select total number of rows, N first and N last rows from in a single query. (It is not the task that I want to achieve just an example of the issue)
Is it expected behavior or a bug in postgres?  I'm using postgres 9.6

```
select generate_series(1, 10) id
into q;

select
       count(*) over (),
       lag(id , 0) over (order by id asc) a,
       lag(id , 0) over (order by id desc) d
from q
limit 5;
```

Output:

```
10,10,10
10,9,9
10,8,8
10,7,7
10,6,6
```

Expected:

```
10,1,10
10,2,9
10,3,8
10,4,7
10,5,6
```

Code work good if only N first or only N last rows are selected.

Comment: you need to use window or aggregate function with 'over'. 'id over (order by id)' is not  
a valid sql

Comment: `lag(...,0)` is a do-nothing operation.  Why would the sort order matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I once had a similar problem which had the same explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668220/3984221

---

Explanation of the behaviour:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4d675744c0aa39ee946f4fa8e7ee5b7c)

You can explain this when you have a look into the EXPLAIN output:

```
> | QUERY PLAN                                                                                                                   |
> | :--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | WindowAgg  (cost=368.69..445.19 rows=2550 width=20) (actual time=0.146..0.150 rows=10 loops=1)                               |
> |   -&gt;  WindowAgg  (cost=368.69..413.32 rows=2550 width=12) (actual time=0.128..0.136 rows=10 loops=1)                         |
> |         -&gt;  Sort  (cost=368.69..375.07 rows=2550 width=8) (actual time=0.126..0.128 rows=10 loops=1)                         |
> |               Sort Key: id                                                                                                   |
> |               Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                                           |
> |               -&gt;  WindowAgg  (cost=179.78..224.41 rows=2550 width=8) (actual time=0.048..0.056 rows=10 loops=1)              |
> |                     -&gt;  Sort  (cost=179.78..186.16 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.033..0.034 rows=10 loops=1)             |
> |                           Sort Key: id DESC                                                                                  |
> |                           Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB                                                               |
> |                           -&gt;  Seq Scan on q  (cost=0.00..35.50 rows=2550 width=4) (actual time=0.013..0.014 rows=10 loops=1) |
> | Planning Time: 0.292 ms                                                                                                      |
> | Execution Time: 0.445 ms                                                                                                     |
```

Here you can see: First there is a `SORT Key: id DESC`. So everything is ordered in `DESC` order. If you have only the `DESC` ordered function, this would be your result, as you already saw. Now, you have a second window function. So, the entire result will be sorted a second time, into the `ASC` order, incl. your first result. So, your first `lag()` result `10, 9, 8, 7, 6, ...` will be ordered back into `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ...` Afterwards the second `lag()` result will be added.

However, your specific result for your `lag()` function is explainable, of course: You don't shift your data, so you get the current value. You can cross check this (as I did in the fiddle above), when you turn your `0` shift value into `1`. Then your `DESC` `lag()` will return `2` for `id 1`, but `ASC` gives `NULL`. Everything's fine.

So, to create your expected output, you need another approach, e.g. using `row_number()` to add the row count in `ASC` and `DESC` order and filter them afterwards:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=7a60595dcaa77a5bcdb069eb831c6b54)

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) OVER (),
    a.id,
    d.id
FROM ( 
   select
       id,
       row_number() over (order by id asc)
   from q
) a
JOIN ( 
   select
       id,
       row_number() over (order by id desc)
   from q
) d ON a.row_number = d.row_number
LIMIT 5
```

Comment: yes, you are right, the order of data is only determined by the query itself. I was confused that 'order by' inside window function change total order of the data. Perfectly valid behavior since there is no 'order by' on the query itself

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of `lag()` determines how many rows to look back. So `lag(id, 0)` means to look back zero rows, which makes `lag(id, 0)` equivalent of just `id`. So the result you get is perfectly sane.

Do get what you want, you can use `row_number()` to join on.

```
SELECT count(*) OVER (),
       x1.id,
       x2.id
       FROM (SELECT id,
                    row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) r
                    FROM q) x1
            INNER JOIN (SELECT id,
                               row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id DESC) r
                               FROM q) x2
                       ON x2.r = x1.r
      ORDER BY x1.r
      LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: Maybe ijrandom wants a default value, so `lag(id, 1, 0)` would be appropriate

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Hmm, possible (as almost everything is). But there are no `0`s in their expected result, so... maybe not? I guess they somehow believed that window functions order the column in question in one way while the rest is ordered in another way and joined which would make it a neat trick to get the expected result. Except that it doesn't work that way...

Comment: yes, may be I misunderstand how the window functions works. Try comment 'lag(id, 0) over (order by id asc) a,' or 'lag(id, 0) over (order by id desc) d'. The query will produce valid output. combine them both and one of 'order by' clause is ignored

Comment: change order of 'a' and 'd' column and the output will be different. It looks for me like a bug. Either output should be different or at least postgres should complain that it is not possible to use multiple order by

Answer (score 0):

Order from one of the over clause are applied to the data. But data only sorted once. The desired behavior could be achieved by following query.

```
select count(*) over (),
       (array_agg(id) over (order by id asc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded  following))[row_number() over ()] a,
       (array_agg(id) over (order by id desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded  following))[row_number() over ()] d
from q
order by id
limit 5
```

maybe memory ineffective for large tables because array_agg construct array from all rows.